# Integrate Google Calendar with Java back-end on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, google-calendar-api

I want to know how to integrate my java backend on GAE with google calendar API?

Problem: Making a mobile organizer on a cloud platform, instead of re-inventing the wheel i decided to use Google calendar's features and add some extra features to my back-end, the point i am stuck in the way to integrate both.. so i would be grateful if someone hints me

Comment: What did you try? Did you read that https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp & https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/?

Comment: Actually i tried to look through it but i couldn't understand that much, its my first time to deal with APIs and backends so am kinda beginner.. i was looking for something more clear